# PHP - Simple Hit Counter

Tags: php, hitcounter

What is the best way to create a hit counter for multiple pages, and to optimize performance at the same time. For example, I would like a unique hit counter on each different blog post, as well as the main page. To make it unique, I would have to store the users IP address in the database, or in a text file. Could I store it in a cookie? I'm not too familiar with cookies, and this sentence might make no sense at all.

Anyway, what is the best way to create separate unique view counters for different pages in PHP?

Comment: If you're not enough confident in technology - it might be better to start with Google Analytics, the tool that has been built by professionals

Comment: No, I know how to do it and am confident it will work, but it just seems like such a resource hog for what seems like it should be a fairly simple thing to do.

Comment: if you know *how to do it*, what is your question about then?

Comment: Should I store the users IP in a database, or store a cookie on their computer, so as not to add a hit to the hit-counter when they re-visit the page?

Comment: choose the one that fits best **your** reqiurements.

Comment: OK, well, is one drastically faster than the other (not to familiar with cookies)?

Comment: don't start trying to optimize not even written software. ps: so read about cookies, it is not that difficult to understand.

Comment: Why wouldn't you try to optimize software before it's written? It's much easier than going back in later and cleaning it up. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I don't do it because no one could predict the possible bottlenecks. Performant software - is simple written software.

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting grilled for your question but I say if you want it done right, you gotta do it yourself. Right?

In my humble opinion, I would have it submit 2 values to a database. (1) the "unique" visitors, which would only be stored when the user DOESN'T have that cookie, and (2) the "page view" visitors, which would be stored regardless of the status of their cookie. Make sure it's an "int"-type field so that it doesn't use as much memory as say a float, double, or text.

Lastly, I would say that you SHOULD optimize unwritten software. That's the point of planning it out before you implement code. There's an old saying, "Measure twice, cut once".